# Expected chain length after rehashing - Linear Hashing

Tags: hash, hashtable

There is one confusion I've about load factor. Some sources say that it is just the number of keys in hash table divided by total number of slots which is same as expected chain length for each slot. But that is only in simple uniform hashing right?

Suppose hash table T has n elements and we expand T into T1 by redistributing elements in slot T[0] by rehashing them using h'(k) = k mod 2m. The hash function of T1 is h(k) = k mod 2m if h(k) < 1 and k mod m if h(k) >= 1. Many sources say that we "Expand and rehash to maintain the load factor (does this imply expected chain length is still same?) Since this is not simple uniform hashing, I think the probability that any key k enters a slot is (1/4 + 1/2(m-1)). 
For a key k (randomly selected), h(k) is first evaluated (there are 50-50 chances whether it is less than 1 or greater than or equal to 1) and then if it's less than 1, key k has JUST two ways - slot 0 or slot m. Hence, probability 1/4 (1/2 * 1/2) But if it is greater than or equal to 1, it has m-1 slots and could enter any and hence probability (1/2 * 1/m-1). So expected chain length would now be n/4 + n/2(m-1). Am I on right track?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for linear hashing should be the same as for "non-linear" hashing.  With a certain initial number of buckets, uniform distribution of hash values would result in uniform placement.  With enough expansions to double the size of the table, each of those values would be randomly split over the larger space via the incremental re-hashing, and new values would also have been distributed over the larger space.  Incrementally, each point is equally likely to be at (initial bucket position) and (2x initial bucket position) as the table expands to that length.

There is a paper [here](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy460/pdf/Dynamic%20Hash%20Tables.pdf) which goes into detail about the chain length calculation under different circumstances (not just the average), specifically for linear hashing.